# bootstrap navbar-brand stretches when collapsed menu is opened on iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm having some trouble with a simple bootstrap navbar in deployment. When I view it on a mobile device (Apple iPhone4s) and click to expand the menu options, the navbar-brand element and the button get stretched vertically to fill the length of the menu.

Website is: www.jonathantr.com 
Github repo is: https://github.com/JonathanTR/JonathanTR.github.io

Any thoughts? I'd be happy to post any more specific code snippets needed. I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS below seems to be the issue...Once removed, the issue went away.

```
.affix, .navbar-fixed-top {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); 
}
```

I was able to recreate the issue [here](http://bootply.com/107302)

Comment: Hmmm - I tried that too - also not working. Can't seem to replicate it in the bootstrap fiddle you provided, either.

Comment: That is for sure the problem... I can recreate and fix the issue at will with that bootply.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the very simple fact that I did not have sass --watch on when I made those changes. Thanks for your help!